# Which mail clients support PGP/MIME - is there an overview?

Tags: encryption, email, pgp, digital-signature

Does anyone know if there is a current overview (I only found ones from before 2006) which MUAs (mail clients) do support PGP/MIME?

I wonder whether there still exist issues like "Outlook Express does not support PGP/MIME" or whether this issue can meanwhile be neglected?

Thanks for any pointers...

Regards.

P.S.: This post is related to the more complex question I asked 2 weeks ago which unfortunately nobody could answer: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52417/s-mime-vs-pgp-mail-clients-with-pgp-mime-support - hope it is fine to ask a simpler, even though related, question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia has a table full of answers in its [Comparison of Email Clients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_email_clients#General_features).  No telling when the table was last updated, but probably newer than 2006.  Yes, by all accounts, Outlook Express is still broken (surprised?  I should hope *not*).

Comment: Awesome... sometimes the answer is soo easy... thanks!